# Internet Explorer throwing routing exception but Chrome is ok, in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm getting an exception when routing to different action methods on different controllers if I don't have a forward slash after the url. The routing engine does route me, I just receive an exception if there isn't a forward slash in the url and I'm debugging using Internet Explorer, Chrome works fine. It seems like it's first looking for a default url of index, then if not found it looks at what has been passed in. I could be wrong here...

This works with no exception if I add a forward slash after it's rendered.

```
<a class="btn-sm" style="font-size: 1em; font-weight: bold;" href="/profile/general/">Profile</a>
```

This routes me to the url but with an exception, if I'm using IE. If I use Chrome it works fine, no exception.

```
<a class="btn-sm" style="font-size: 1em; font-weight: bold;" href="/profile/general">Profile</a>
```

Here is the exception

> System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'Index' was not found on controller 'YogaBand2017.Controllers.ProfileController'.

Here is the action method

```
public ActionResult General()
    {
        try
        {
            ViewBag.MenuItem = "profile";
            ViewBag.UserMenuItem = "general";

            var viewModel = _yogaProfileService.GetGeneralInfo(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorService.LogError(ex, Request);
            ViewBag.Message = "Oh No! Something went wrong fetching your info. We're looking into this now!";
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

Here is my routeconfig file

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SpaceCleanRoute",
            url: "space/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "space", action = "index" },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PublicSpaceRoute",
            url: "space/public/{title}",
            defaults: new { controller = "space", action = "public" },
            constraints: new { title = @"^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
}
```

Here is the action link before it gets rendered

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "general", "profile", new { }, new { @class = "btn-sm", @style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 1em;" })
```

Comment: So are you saying `Html.ActionLink` renders into a URL without a forward slash in one case and with a forward slash in another?

Comment: no it always renders without a forward slash. And IE will throw an exception, Chrome doesn't. But if I add a forward slash IE works fine.

Comment: Works fine for me without a slash in IE.

Comment: ya it works fine for me in Chrome and Edge, but IE seems to be throwing an exception. I tried resetting all the browsers cashes and cleraring out data in the browsers but still IE throws